# Getting data from a site running javascript

Tags: php

I have problem from getting offine data . That site running javascript to show time & date. I want to get that details but failed . I tried to save offine web page and view source i can see that date easily but when running my script it cant get the date . The code below :

```
$url_data           = file_get_contents('http://www.nowgoal.com/analysis/1415915.html');
$rows               = explode("\n", $url_data);
//Tried to echo the row 137 to see the date but it didnt show it. i think this fucntion file_get_contents dont run javascript.  
echo htmlentities($rows[137]);
```

is there any ideals to get this date ? I really appreciate your helps. Thank guys.

Comment: This is PHP, why do you tag it as JavaScript?

Comment: The dates on the target webpage are added via javascript so you will not be able to use php to find them. Consider using node.js perhaps?

Comment: Tks guy . i got it . Nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the source code of the page in the sample notice how the dates are prepared - their server side inserts a JS command to set the date, like this:
    formatDate('2017,6,5,15,00,00',3)
They're using their own function formatDate, which you can find in this file:
http://www.nowgoal.com/data/public.js

If you fetch the page via PHP you would get the original string of formatDate and will have to separate the params and pass them to date or [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) for example (depends on what you want to use the date for)

Comment: Tks Danyv . i got it .